# Enums via Markup in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, enums

I have an enum and a usercontrol, both in the same assembly (a plain .NET 4 web site).

**In the Constants class:**

```
public Enum CrudOperations
    Add
    Edit
    Delete
```

This controls the columns in a GridView on a UserControl via a property on the UserControl

```
Public Property Mode() As CrudOperations
        Get
            Return [Enum].Parse(GetType(CrudOperations), If(ViewState.Item("Mode"), "0"), True)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As CrudOperations)
            ViewState.Item("Mode") = value
            grdItems.Columns(3).Visible = ((value Or CrudOperations.Add) = CrudOperations.Add)
            grdItems.Columns(4).Visible = ((value Or CrudOperations.Edit) = CrudOperations.Edit)
        End Set
End Property
```

In C#, I've specified the columns to show with markup as `Mode="Edit,Delete"`, but in VB.NET, this does nothing. The only way I can get anything to show is with the codebehind, but if on the containing page I use `userGrid.Mode = CrudOperations.Edit And CrudOperations.Delete`, I get all the columns (there's also a delete column), but `userGrid.Mode = CrudOperations.Edit Or CrudOperations.Delete` shows nothing.

Is there a way to do the C# equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Flags` attribute where an enumeration can be treated as a bit field.

C#:

```
[Flags] 
public enum CrudOperations 
{ 
    Add, 
    Edit, 
    Delete  
}

userGrid.Mode = CrudOperations.Edit | CrudOperations.Delete;
```

VB.NET:

```
<Flags> _
Public Enum CrudOperations
    Add
    Edit
    Delete
End Enum

Private test As CrudOperations = CrudOperations.Edit Or CrudOperations.Delete
```

Comment: Alternatively (in VB.NET anyway), you can just assign the values in Base2: Add = 1, Edit = 2, Delete = 4, and then use logical AND and logical OR, or addition: userGrid.Mode = Edit + Delete.

Comment: Thatnks. I guess it was the line continuation character. To check the flag is set, you then need to use `((value And CrudOperations.Edit) = CrudOperations.Edit)`